# How to retrieve id sent from a link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to to edit a form through a reveal-modal. So i have multiple posts.

When I click the link **'Edit'** it will reveal a **div** and display a form inside that is repopulated with the information. However, I don't know how to pass the post id into the form it will know which post to edit.

If i try to render the partial form I get this error:

> undefined method `model_name' for Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class

All my information are on a controller view that is called Dashboard

---

**controllers/dashboards_controller.rb**

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @profile = Profile.find(current_user)
    @profileAll = Profile.all
    @post = Post.all
end

def show

end

def edit
    @profile =Profile.find(current_user)
    @post = @profile.post.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

---

**controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @profile = Profile.find(current_user)
    @post = @profile.post.create(post_params)
    redirect_to dashboards_path(current_user)
end

def destroy
    @post =Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
    @post = profile.post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to dashboards_path(current_user)

end

def show 
    @profile =Profile.find(current_user)
    @post = @profile.post.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @profile =Profile.find(current_user)
    @post = @profile.post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = profile.post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to dashboards_path(current_user)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end


private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

---

**posts/_form2.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
  this post from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
 <%= f.label :content %><br>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

---

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get 'homepages/index'
 resources 'dashboards' do 
  resources 'posts'
end
#get 'users/sign_in'
resources 'profiles' do 
 resources 'posts'
end

devise_for :users, :controller => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}

devise_scope :user do 
 root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
end
end
```

---

**Dashboards/index.html.erb**

```
 <% @post.each do |post| %>
 <div class="panel">
 <%= @profileAll.find(post.profile_id).name  %>
 <hr>
 <h5><%= post.title %></h5>
 <p><%= post.content %></p>

 <%# link_to "Edit",  edit_dashboard_post_path(current_user,[post.profile, post]) %>
 <%= link_to "Edit", {id: @post},'data-reveal-id' => 'edit-post' %>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <div id="edit-post" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
   <%= render 'posts/form2'  %>

  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: change this line and try once: `<%= link_to "Edit", {id: post.id},'data-reveal-id' => 'edit-post' %>`

Comment: Did not work i got this error:undefined method `id' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb5e06a7c>

Comment: try this `<%= link_to "Edit", {id: @post},'data-reveal-id' => 'edit-post' %>` and then `   <%= render 'posts/form2', locals: {post: @post}  %>`

Comment: Thanks for help anusha, but its now telling me this error on my form: undefined method `model_name' for Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class

Comment: actually the error is because you are retrieving posts using this `@post = @profile.post.find(params[:id])` but the id is empty so try this once `remove the above line in dashboard edit method and add these <%= link_to "Edit", edit_dashboard_post_path(current_user,[post.profile, post]),'data-reveal-id' => 'edit-post' %> and then ` <%= render 'posts/form2', locals: {post: @post} %>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it simply does not work that way. First, you have in your controller `@post = Post.all` and within your `_form2.html.erb` you want to render form for a collection. That should be:

```
# index.html.erb
<div id="edit-post" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
   <%= render :partial => 'posts/form2', collection: @posts  %>

  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
 </div>

#dashboard controller:
def index
    #...
    @posts = Post.all
end
```

`_form2.html.erb`:
Every `@post` object instance has to be replaced with `form2`. Read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html about rendering a collection.

However, consider a case when you have hundreds of posts. Then, for each post, a partial is rendered. That would be very inefficient so instead, consider an asynchronous request which will load only one post the user requested.

Comment: it gives me this error when I replace every @post in the form to form2: undefined local variable or method `form2' for #<#<Class:0xba886c0>:0xb5c0ac14>

Comment: Add `partial` to the render method: `<%= render :partial => 'posts/form2', collection: @posts  %>`. I've updated my response.

Comment: Hey thanks, its not giving me any errors anymore but its not rendering the form. The div is just blank.

Comment: And are you sure you have some posts in database?

Comment: yes , i do have some posts. I can output them without a form. What concerns me the most is that It does not even display the form elements at all. Its just a div with nothing. No input elements or label elements. Thanks again for your support bleump.

Comment: Well, if `div` is empty, then it seems the `@posts` collection appears to be empty. Did you also checked the html tree? Perhaps it is just hidden? Haven't you missed the equal operator for `<% %>` (should be `<%=  %>`)? I cannot see any other issue here.

Comment: hey I know why it wasn't working but I am still not getting any result can you explain to how do I transfer the id of the selected post to the form. Because this is the error that I getting:No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"dashboards", :format=>"3"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Pretty what i am trying to do is to be able to edit my comment of the same page without having to go to an edit page.

Comment: Have you tried to change `link_to` as suggested above, I mean: `<%= link_to "Edit", {id: post.id},'data-reveal-id' => 'edit-post' %>`? I am not a fan of having links with just a hash (because it makes your code unclear) and I do prefer the `resource_path()` methods.